# center a panel on screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and creating a panel. I'm trying to center my panel in the middle of the screen. It's inside a container.

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-title text-center">Log in</div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
             <h6>Use a local account to log in.</h6> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one approach:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxn6ps5s/)

```
.container .panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

If you're interested in other approaches, [**see this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564).

Answer (score 2):

For others, like me, who came here looking to center panel only horizontally and not vertically, col-xx-offset is a quick way to center a panel horizontally.

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002430/1526703) answer