# How to center div with col-md-6?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display in the center the div with `class="col-md-6"`

This is the code, that display me the timer at the left I nee to display time in the center

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container col-md-6">
      <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="event-wrapper featured-event  ">

            <!-- the loop -->
            <div class="upcoming-campaign">
              <img width="555" height="400" src="http://andrejceccoli.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/elezioni_sfondo.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Elezioni Politiche">
              <div class="campaign-scoop">
                <h3 class="title"><a href="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/event/election-campaign/">Elezioni Politiche</a></h3>

                <span class="start-date">Inizia il: <span class="colored">20 Nov 2016</span></span>

                <div class="countdown-wrapper">
                  <ul class="countdown list-inline" data-countdown="2016-11-20">
                    <li><span class="days">38<span><p>Days</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="hours">07<span><p>Hour</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="minutes">48<span><p>Minutes</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="second">12<span><p>Second</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <address><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>San Marino</address>
                <span class="event-duration colored"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>08:00 AM - 23:00 PM</span>
              </div>
              <!-- .campaign-scoop -->
            </div>
            <!-- .upcoming-campaign -->
            <!-- end of the loop -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Declare a css class like, `.col-aligncenter{float: none;margin: 0 auto;}` and place the `.col-aligncenter` after your `col-md-6`

Comment: It is already asked and answered, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088706/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-center-elements-horizontally-or-vertically

Comment: @KnowGe the accepted answer there is bad practice and wrong.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3**

Add the `col-md-offset-3` class that will offset by 3 columns, given that Bootstrap has a 12-column grid this will put a `col-md-6` element right in the center.

[Documentation reference on offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

**Bootstrap 4**

Use `offset-3` or `mx-auto` to center a `col-md-6` column

Answer (score 18):

Just add "float:none;margin:auto;" to your div style like this :

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:auto;">
   .....
</div>
```

Hope to be useful ;)

Answer (score 5):

As I see you are using wordpress. And the code you placed is not end properly. If I'm not wrong there is also other part of col-md-6 you have in the row. 
So easily you can set the time in center .upcoming-campaign { text-align: center; } adding this. If any Question ask me in comment.

```css
.upcoming-campaign {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container col-md-6">
      <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="event-wrapper featured-event  ">

            <!-- the loop -->

            <div class="upcoming-campaign">
              <img width="555" height="400" src="http://andrejceccoli.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/elezioni_sfondo.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="Elezioni Politiche">
              <div class="campaign-scoop">
                <h3 class="title"><a href="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/event/election-campaign/">Elezioni Politiche</a></h3>

                <span class="start-date">Inizia il: <span class="colored">20 Nov 2016</span></span>

                <div class="countdown-wrapper">
                  <ul class="countdown list-inline" data-countdown="2016-11-20">
                    <li><span class="days">38<span><p>Days</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="hours">07<span><p>Hour</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="minutes">48<span><p>Minutes</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="second">12<span><p>Second</p></span></span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                </div>

                <address>
              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>San Marino                            
           </address>

           

 <span class="event-duration colored"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>08:00 AM - 23:00 PM</span>
              </div>
              <!-- .campaign-scoop -->
            </div>
            <!-- .upcoming-campaign -->

            <!-- end of the loop -->


          </div>
          <!-- end of event-wrraper -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of wpb-wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of vc_colum-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of col-md-6 [1] -->

    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container col-md-6">
      <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">


        </div>
        <!-- end of wpb-wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of vc_colum-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of col-md-6 [2] -->

  </div>
  <!-- end of Row -->
</div>
<!-- end of the Container -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are wondering the answer for Bootstrap 5, you need to add `justify-content-md-center` beside to the DIV containing the ROW class.

Documented example [here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#:%7E:text=div%3E%0A%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/div%3E-,Variable%20width%20content,size%20columns%20based%20on%20the%20natural%20width%20of%20their%20content.,-1%20of%203)